# Como pasar objeto VideoView por intent.putextra()

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, video, cast

Estoy tratando de pasar un `VideoView` de una actividad a otra. El `VideoView` en cuestión está en un `Dialog`.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.videoDialog);
dialog.SetTitle("Dialogo");                


VideoView oVisorVideo = dialog.FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.visorCamVideo);               

lblCamTitulo.Text = aPars[2];
string sUri = VideoActivity.LinkRtsp(nGrabador, nCamara);

oVisorVideo.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(sUri));
oVisorVideo.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


oVisorVideo.Start();
oVisorVideo.Click += delegate {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(VideoActivity));
    intent.PutExtra("videoview", Convert.ToString(oVisorVideo));
    StartActivity(intent);
};
```

En mi cabeza sonaba bien hacer un cast de

```
var video = (VideoView)stringVideoView;
```

pero al cargar la activity `VideoView` se me queda vacío.

Hago esto por que obtengo un link rtsp y este tarda bastante en cargar o más bien, en mostrar imagen y había pensado que así el vídeo pasaría con la imagen. Con el stream funcionando.

Comment: Si no me equivoco los parámetros que se pasan al Intent tiene que ser serializables. VideoView no parece serlo. No te sería más fácil pasar la url (string) y crear VideoView en la nueva Activity?

Comment: Si hago eso al pasar el videoview de una activity a la otra tardará unos 15 segundos en empezar a mostrar la imagen... Claro que me sería más fácil, pero no es lo que busco... esto no deja de ser una solución provisional hasta que consiga acelerar la carga del stream.

Comment: has intentado esto: `intent.putExtra("MyVideoView", obj);` y recibirlo así: `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyVideoView");` ?

Comment: @DavidVillegas ¿que es obj? ¿el `VideoView`?

Comment: si @Aritzbn el VideoView

Comment: @DavidVillegas no funcionó